# Vue.js: global base URL of server side application

Tags: vue.js

In a small Vue application I'm working on there is code like this:

`this.axios.post('https://localhost:8000/api/auth/login',.......)`.

The `https://localhost:8000` needs to change after deploying to a server since the server side of the application will be hosted at a different IP address/port. I want to define something like a `BASE_URL` that can be read from a configuration file or something like that, which means the above code would change to something like:

`` this.axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/api/auth/login`) ``

What's the best way to do this within Vue.js? Initially [baseUrl](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl) sounded promising, but that doesn't seem to be what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [environment variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) to define your base url. For example, create files *.env.development* and *.env.production* at the base of your project:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=https://localhost:8000
```

Then, you can specify the base url as part of the axios config:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
```

The vue application will change depending what mode you use to build, for example `npm run build --  --mode development` or `npm run build -- --mode production`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .env file in your root, and reference that: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes